# Having trouble with a simple WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been going nuts over this, and I know it's a small fix. Down below is my SQL code and I am having problems inserting a where clause (`where feed_opn_9132 = 'TOHO'`)

This code does what I want it to do but doesn't display `feed_opn_9132 = 'TOHO`' Data. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!!
Code:

```
SELECT device, fsi_opns,
CASE WHEN opn_wip IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE opn_wip END AS opn_wip, 
feed_opn_9109, feed_opn_9132, feed_opn_9122, feed_opn_9131, feed_opn_9124, starting_material, boat, sort_opns, in_bank, plan_bank, in_bank-plan_bank AS DELTA, loop
from
(SELECT a.device, a.fsi_opns, c.opn_wip, a.feed_opn_9109, a.feed_opn_9132, a.feed_opn_9122, a.feed_opn_9131, a.feed_opn_9124, a.starting_material, a.sort_opns, b.in_bank, d.plan_bank, d.loop, a.boat
from

(SELECT device, fsi_opns, feed_opn_9109, feed_opn_9132, feed_opn_9122, feed_opn_9131, feed_opn_9124, starting_material, sort_opns, BOAT 
FROM pilot_feed_opn
Where feed_opn_9132 = 'TOHO') a,

    (SELECT device, Sum(in_qty) AS in_bank
    FROM LOT_MOVE_AGE@smsdwde2.itg.ti.com
    WHERE facility = 'DP1DM5'

    AND device = ANY(SELECT device
                              FROM dm_device_attributes@smsdwde2.itg.ti.com
                              WHERE facility = 'DP1DM5'
                              AND status = 'A'
                              AND family LIKE 'PILOT%'
                              )
    AND departure_dttm IS null AND latest = 'O'
    AND (lpt = ANY(SELECT lpt
                    FROM pilot_lpts
                    WHERE facility = 'DP1DM5'
                    AND category = 'Bank'
                    )
    OR opn = ANY('0048','9050'))
    GROUP BY device
    ORDER BY device) b,

(select device, Sum(in_qty) AS opn_wip
FROM LOT_MOVE_AGE@smsdwde2.itg.ti.com
WHERE facility = 'DP1DM5'
AND device = ANY(SELECT device
                  FROM dm_device_attributes@smsdwde2.itg.ti.com
                  WHERE facility = 'DP1DM5'
                  AND status = 'A'
                  AND family LIKE 'PILOT%')
AND departure_dttm IS null AND latest = 'O'
AND opn = ANY( '9109', '9132', '9122','9131', '9124')

GROUP BY device
ORDER BY device) c,

(SELECT device, plan_bank, loop 
FROM pilot_goals) d


WHERE a.device = b.device
AND a.device = c.device
AND a.device = d.device(+))

ORDER BY  opn_wip desc
```

Old output:
[image]

New Output:
[image]

Here is all the data that should be populated on the table.
[image]

Comment: Paul, I know a lot of people like the consistency of auto-formatting, but I feel like in this case it makes it much harder to see the whole query at once. :(

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways of thinking.

You'll often get better performance if you add your filter/where at the lowest possible level:

```
(SELECT device, fsi_opns, feed_opn_9109, feed_opn_9132, feed_opn_9122, feed_opn_9131, feed_opn_9124, starting_material, sort_opns, BOAT 
FROM pilot_feed_opn
where feed_opn_9132 = 'TOHO') a,
```

However, if you have more complicated logic (aggregate counts, etc) it's often safer to put your filter in the outermost query.

EDIT: if you expect to be getting more rows back, the main things limiting your rows are your inner joins between a-b and b-c. Try changing them to outer joins, like this:

```
WHERE a.device = b.device(+)
AND a.device = c.device(+)
AND a.device = d.device(+))
ORDER BY  opn_wip desc
```

In your case, it doesn't look like it would make much of a difference, since the `feed_opn_9132` column isn't part of any aggregate queries. I'd probably go with the first option.

Comment: Hi @kfinity thank you for the quick response. For some reason, it is still not pulling in the data. the SQL Querry runs but no output.

Comment: @Dc5nipe could you edit your question and add the full query which is returning 0 results?

Comment: I didn't mean to say "no output" I meant to say "no correct output"

Comment: @Dc5nipe oh - your question says `feed_opn_9132 = 'TOHO'` but in your output image you've highlighted the `feed_opn_9131` column - is that what you want? You could just change 9132 to 9131 in the where clause and it should just display those 3 rows.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why its highlighted like that. What I need is all the Feed_opn but for Feed_opn_9132 I need all the ones that have a value of  `TOHO`

Comment: I added a new picture to the post.

Comment: @Dc5nipe So is the problem that you aren't getting as many rows as you expect? If so, it's probably your inner joins. I'll edit my answer to clarify that.